# SQL Syntax unfamiliar

Tags: mysql, sql

The code and statements below are from a task from university. Why are a & b are being used in this syntax?

1. Formulate an SQL statement: From the Country table, find a sorted list of countries, each of which is the largest on their continent. The continent is the continent on which most of the area of a country is located.
2. Returns names and first names for customers for whom a delivery note has been saved.
3. SELECT Name, Continent FROM Country AS a WHERE Percentage > 50 AND Area >= (SELECT MAX(Area) FROM Country AS b WHERE a.Continent=b.Continent AND b.Percentage > 50) ORDER BY Name;
4. SELECT Name, Firstname FROM customer a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CustomerDeliveryAddress FROM Adress b WHERE b.CustomerDeliveryAddress = a.CustomerID)

Comment: Please see [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166) and

[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1288408)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the person writing the query doesn't know enough about writing good queries.  What are needed are table aliases.  That is because you need to distinguish the column references in the (correlated) subquery from the column references to the outer query.

However, it is strongly recommended that you use meaningful table aliases -- and that means table abbreviations.  You should also qualify all column names.

So, the first of the queries should look more like this:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Continent
FROM Country c
WHERE c.Percentage > 50 AND
      c.Area >= (SELECT MAX(c2.Area)
                 FROM Country c2
                 WHERE c2.Continent = c.Continent AND
-----------------------^ this is the correlation clause that references columns in both the inner and outer queries
                 c2.Percentage > 50
                )
ORDER BY Name;
```

It is also highly misleading to use `>=` in this syntax, because you are looking at the maximum value.